# 2D zoom, scale and translation

Tags: android, translation, zooming, scale

I am trying to create a method of resizing a bitmaps scale (by Pinch Zoom) and then centering it on the screen. But whenever I zoom out, it gets smaller from the upper-left corner, and when I zoom in it grows to the lower-right:

```
 public void ZoomIn() {
        TileMap.TileSize += 2;

        Position.x += 1;
        Position.y += 1;
    }
```

I tried offsetting it by shifting the position of sprite but it doesn't work. I don't know the ratio.

How do you scale a sprite (Bitmap) and have it remain at the same position on screen (grow from center, I guess)?

Answer (score 0):

Consider vertically then horizontally.

If the width of the bitmap changes by +10 pixels then to centre horizontally in the same place you need to shift it's position by -5 pixels.

Same for the height. Store previous value and current value, calculate difference, shift right by `floor(widthDiff / 2)` and shift up by `floor(heightDiff / 2)`.